# Unable to Fetch particular product for each category

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-templates

I am always getting all the food items in all Categories.
I want to display each **Category** with each **food** item.
Need to display Category with item belonging to that Category.
Please someone help me on this issue to resolve. I have tried looking over internet but couldn't find the solution to it

models.py

```py
class Category(models.Model):
       category_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
 
       def __str__(self):
        return self.category_name


class Menu(models.Model):

    dish_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Name of Dish')
    Desc = models.TextField(verbose_name='Dish Description')
    Amount = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False, verbose_name='Amount of Dish')
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, verbose_name='Dish Date Posted')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.dish_name
```

views.py

```py
def menu(request):

    products = Menu.objects.all()

    categories = Category.objects.all()

    data = {}
    data['products'] = products
    data['categories'] = categories
    template = 'food/menu.html'
    return render(request, template, data)
```

html

```html
{% for category in categories %}

    {% if categories %}

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
          <div class="menu-section">
            <h2 class="menu-section-title">{{ category.category_name }}</h2>
            <hr>
            {% endif %}

              {% for i in products %}
              <div class="menu-item">
                <div class="menu-item-name">{{ i.dish_name}}</div>
                <div class="menu-item-price">Rs {{ i.Amount}}</div>
                <div class="menu-item-description">{{ i.Desc}}</div>
              </div>
              {% endfor %}
          </div>
        </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not filtering products based on categoris.

I would suggest doing something like this with data:

```
data = {
    'categories': {
        category: Menu.objects.filter(category=category) for category in categories
        }
    }
```

and in html you can:

```
{% for category, products in categories.items %}
    {% if products %}

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
      <div class="menu-section">
        <h2 class="menu-section-title">{{ category.category_name }}</h2>
        <hr>

          {% for i in products %}
          <div class="menu-item">
            <div class="menu-item-name">{{ i.dish_name}}</div>
            <div class="menu-item-price">Rs {{ i.Amount}}</div>
            <div class="menu-item-description">{{ i.Desc}}</div>
          </div>
          {% endfor %}

      </div>
    </div>

    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I tried but ended up getting error 'Need 2 values to unpack in for loop; got 1'
Can you help me resolve it?

Comment: hi, sorry for late reply: try ` {% for category, products in categories.items %}` or ` {% for category, products in categories.items() %}`in first line

Comment: Hi , Thanks for so much help ..It is working now with (.items) . can you edit your main answer with this so that I can mark that as a answer..